# How to fix Maximum update depth exceeded Error occuring in ComponentWillMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, state, react-component

I have searched this issue, but related cases to this issue are not same as mine.

I have **React client side** where Im using react-big-scheduler. In **ComponentDidMount** I have to do **API axios** calls and set state with response data.

```js
componentWillMount() {
  let today = moment().format(DATE_FORMAT);
  let schedulerData = new SchedulerData(today, ViewTypes.Week);
  schedulerData.localeMoment.locale('en');

  const token = localStorage.getItem("jwttoken");
  axios.post('http://localhost/Auth/api/validate.php', {
      "jwt": token
    }, {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      this.setState({
        vendor: response.data.data
      })
      const vid = response.data.data.VendorID;

      return axios.get('http://localhost/Auth/api/show_all_HR.php?VendorID=' + vid, {
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
          schedulerData.setResources(response.data);
          this.setState({
            AllHR: response.data,
            viewModel: schedulerData
          });
          console.log("I should be rendered at 1st", this.state.AllHR);
          console.log(vid);
        });
    });



  axios.get('http://localhost/Auth/api/show_one_HR_hours.php?VendorID=48', {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      schedulerData.setEvents(response.data);
      this.setState({
        AllSlots: response.data,
        viewModel: schedulerData
      });
    });

}
```

Now I get this Error for doing setState:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

Now All other solutions suggest that problem occurs when we call the function in **onClick** or put the () after function. But I have no such thing.

So Please suggest me what to change in my code?

EDIT:
I render it like this:

```js
render() {
    const {viewModel} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
         <Row style={ {width: "100%"}}>
            <h3> Schedule Maintenance Service Time Slots</h3>
            <Scheduler schedulerData={viewModel}
               prevClick={this.prevClick}
               nextClick={this.nextClick}
               onSelectDate={this.onSelectDate}
               onViewChange={ this.onViewChange}
               eventItemClick={this.eventClicked}
               viewEventClick={this.ops1}
               viewEventText="Ops 1"
               viewEvent2Text="Ops 2"
               viewEvent2Click={this.ops2}
               updateEventStart={this.updateEventStart}
               updateEventEnd={this.updateEventEnd}
               moveEvent={this.moveEvent}
               newEvent={this.newEvent}
               leftCustomHeader={leftCustomHeader}
               toggleExpandFunc={this.toggleExpandFunc}
           />
        </Row>
     </div>
   );
}

prevClick = (schedulerData) => {
  schedulerData.prev();
  schedulerData.setEvents(this.state.AllSlots);
  this.setState({
    viewModel: schedulerData
  })
}

nextClick = (schedulerData) => {
  schedulerData.next();
  schedulerData.setEvents(this.state.AllSlots);
  this.setState({
    viewModel: schedulerData
  })
}

onViewChange = (schedulerData, view) => {
  schedulerData.setViewType(view.viewType, view.showAgenda, view.isEventPerspective);
  schedulerData.setEvents(this.state.AllSlots);
  console.log("Im changing VIEW");

}
```

Comment: You should consolidate all of your calls to `setState()` into the final `.then()`. Since these are all nested, you have access to the initial response data as well as the final response in the final call to `.then()`. So put all of you `setState()` there.

Comment: You should put those calls in componentDidMount, not componentWillMount. componentWillMount will be removed in next version: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks for replying. I did the same as told by u but now it gives me this error:  **Uncaught TypeError: schedulerData._setDocumentWidth is not a function** and it refers to the react-big-scheduler 's index.js file which I never touched. It came with the installation. Now what to do?

Comment: @user2343647 Yes I tried with componentDidMount and it always throw the error I mentioned in above comment so I have to do it with componentWillMount

Comment: componetWillMount is the worst place to make calls with side effects. And it will be retired with ReactJS 17. Btw, you should use redux and redux-saga (or redux-thunk) to make your asynchronous calls. You realize that componentWillMount finishes before any data comes back, right? Write console.log statements when componentWillMount ends and when you "then" are invoked. The only way around this is to use async and await, which are part of es7.

Using redux and redux-saga is the best way to go. Your component should not make outside calls. Bad practice.

Comment: Now I changed it componentDidMount but it gives same above error without showing any console.log values.

Comment: @user2343647 where would I use await for this? or Maybe this is error with react-big-scheduler?